# Select data from one table base on selection from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 3 table

First contain the item with price on given dates

2nd is the table of items

3rd is the table of dates in which we want to show the price of 2nd table item on every date

if duration is not available on first table it should be 0

```
with myTable ( item,startdate,enddate,price) as 
(  
  select  'AAAA' ,'16-3-2020','19-3-2020','50' union all
  select  'AAAA' ,'16-4-2020','19-4-2020','70' union all
  select  'BBB' ,'16-3-2020','19-3-2020','20' union all
  select  'BBB' ,'16-4-2020','19-4-2020','90' union all
  select  'CCC' ,'16-3-2020','29-3-2020','45' union all
  select  'CCC' ,'16-4-2020','19-4-2020','120'
)
select  item,startdate,enddate,price  from myTable
GO

with itemTable ( item) as 
(  
  select  'AAAA'  union all
  select  'BBB'  union all
   select  'CCC' 
)
select  item  from itemTable

GO

with DateTable ( dateItem) as 
(  
  select  '16-3-2020'  union all
  select  '19-4-2020'  union all
  select  '20-3-2020' 
)
select  dateItem  from DateTable

GO
```

and my desire result should be like this (above is dynamic data)

```
with mydesireTable (item, [16-3-2020],[19-4-2020],[20-3-2020]) as 
(  
  select  'AAAA' ,'50','70','0' union all ---0 as its not on above  data in duration 
  select  'BBB' ,'20','90','0' union all
  select  'CCC' ,'45','120','45' 
)
select  item, [16-3-2020],[19-4-2020],[20-3-2020]  from mydesireTable
```

I am  not sure what to search for :) as i want to write query for it which return my desire table as data ( or as in temporary table )

Comment: First you need to write a query that joins those three tables up correctly. Then you need to build a crosstab query over that

Comment: there is no key in 2nd and 3rd table so not sure how to join

Comment: Yes `itemTable` is redundant. But in order to "bucket" your dates in the way you require you need something like `ON DateTable.dateItem BETWEEN myTable.startdate AND  myTable.enddate`. Then you can map multiple records in MyTable to a DateTable.dateitem. You'll get an extra column `DateTable.dateitem` which you need to pivot

Comment: can you please translate that into English :)

Comment: :D I can probably post an answer but first, are the dates in DateTable dynamic or fixed? are there only three? Because you probably require a dynamic crosstab and I usually just say "do it in the presentation layer"

Comment: Looking at your data, can you recheck your final CCC line? I think it's meant to be 4, 120, 45

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes its 45,120,45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #myTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#itemTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #itemTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #DateTable;

CREATE TABLE #myTable (
    item VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    startdate DATE NOT NULL,
    enddate DATE NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
    );

INSERT #myTable (item, startdate, enddate, price) VALUES
    ('AAAA' ,CAST('2020-03-16' AS DATE),CAST('2020-03-19' AS DATE),50),
    ('AAAA' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',70), 
    ('BBB' ,'2020-03-16','2020-03-19',20),
    ('BBB' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',90),
    ('CCC' ,'2020-03-16','2020-03-29',45),
    ('CCC' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',120)


CREATE TABLE #itemTable ( 
    item VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT #itemTable (item) VALUES
    ('AAAA'), 
    ('BBB'),
    ('CCC')

CREATE TABLE #DateTable (  
    dateItem DATE NOT NULL
)

INSERT #DateTable (dateItem) VALUES
    (CAST('2020-03-16' AS DATE)), 
    (CAST('2020-04-19' AS DATE)),
    (CAST('2020-03-20' AS DATE)),
    (CAST('2020-03-21' AS DATE)),
    (CAST('2021-03-21' AS DATE)),
    (CAST('2022-03-21' AS DATE))


Declare @DynamicCol nvarchar(max),@DynamicColNull nvarchar(max)
        ,@Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicColNull=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(dateItem),','+'''0'''+') As '+QUOTENAME(dateItem)
                        FROM #DateTable FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')

SELECT @DynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(dateItem) FROM #DateTable FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')

SET @Sql='SELECT [item], '+@DynamicColNull+' From
            (   
            select item, dateitem, price from #myTable 
            inner join #datetable on #datetable.dateItem between #mytable.startdate and #myTable.enddate
            )
            AS Src
            PIVOT
            (
            SUM(price) FOR [dateitem] IN ('+@DynamicCol+')
            )AS Pvt'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Worked if the item has atleast one date in first table , if we have dates which are not first table for every item then desire table become empty :(

Comment: update inner join to left join and add inner join for #itemTable

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways to do this. This is a *static* crosstab. You need to list out all the columns explicitly (twice)

If your columns are dynamic, you need to use a *dynamic* crosstab. You should also consider doing this in your "presentation" layer, i.e. excel or whatever you are handing this over in.

You should consider what you want when something in mytable appears against a bucket twice (this solution will add the prices)

```
with myTable ( item,startdate,enddate,price) as 
(  
  select  'AAAA' ,CAST('2020-03-16' AS DATE),CAST('2020-03-19' AS DATE),50 union all
  select  'AAAA' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',70 union all
  select  'BBB' ,'2020-03-16','2020-03-19',20 union all
  select  'BBB' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',90 union all
  select  'CCC' ,'2020-03-16','2020-03-29',45 union all
  select  'CCC' ,'2020-04-16','2020-04-19',120
),

itemTable ( item) as 
(  
  select  'AAAA'  union all
  select  'BBB'  union all
   select  'CCC' 
)
,DateTable ( dateItem) as 
(  
  select  CAST('2020-03-16' AS DATE)  union all
  select  '2020-04-19'  union all
  select  '2020-03-20' 
)


SELECT item,
[2020-03-16],[2020-04-19], [2020-03-20]
FROM
(
select item, dateitem, price from myTable 
inner join datetable on datetable.dateItem between mytable.startdate and myTable.enddate
) As Src
PIVOT 
( 
SUM(price)
FOR
dateitem IN ([2020-03-16],[2020-03-20],[2020-04-19])
) as P
```

Comment: and what about if columns are dynamic ?  i mean i tried to search cross tabs in SQL but didn't get how to use it in current scenario

Comment: You need to take this query `select item, dateitem, price from myTable 
inner join datetable on datetable.dateItem between mytable.startdate and myTable.enddate` and then search on `t-sql dynamic pivot` in google. Who are you producing this data for? Because normally you would use a reporting tool to do the pivot, not SQL